# quitar una clase bowser-default cuando se selecciona

Tags: html, css, estilos

Tengo un input y necesito que cuando pulse sobre ese elemento, se quite el browser-default de la clase, he visto que por css se puede hacer pero no entiendo como hacerlo con:

```css
input:not([type]),
input[type=text]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=password]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=email]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=url]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=time]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=datetime]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=datetime-local]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=tel]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=number]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=search]:not(.browser-default),
input[type=date]:not(.browser-default),
textarea.materialize-textarea {
  /*aqui el estilo*/
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="emailoid" class=" sinbordefondo browser-default" type="text" placeholder="Email o ID" size="30">
<input id="emailoid2" class=" sinbordefondo" type="text" placeholder="Email o ID 2" size="30">
```

Answer (score 2):

Para quitar clases, puedes hacerlo con un `eventListener` en JS:

```
var myInput = document.querySelector('#emailoid');
myInput.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  this.classList.remove('browser-default')
});
```

Si lo que quieres es simplemente cambiar algún estilo, eso sí lo puedes hacer con CSS añadiendo estilos específicos cuando el enfoque está en el elemento. Algo como:

```
input.browser-default:focus {
  estilos
}
```

Comment: Hola, eso lo entiendo, pero lo que tengo es esa etiqueta con browser-default, y necesito que cuando pulso sobre ella, esa clase, desaparezca, y hacerlo con css

Comment: No se puede eliminar una clase de un elemento HTML con CSS. CSS no permite  modificar el DOM, solamente darle estilos. Lo que buscas es imposible, podrías hacerlo con Javascript tal y como te han dicho en esta respuesta.